# How to display Hive2 command prompt in different color on Linux

Tags: linux, hadoop, hive

We are on RHEL 7.9 and connecting to Hive2 using beeline.
While working from command line, I find it difficult to locate the command prompt to see the previous commands I executed.

Is there any way to change the color of command prompt or in some way make it distinct so it can be found among lots of lines on screen?

Some details about my setup:

```
Connected to: Apache Hive (version 3.1.0.3.1.5.0-152)
Driver: Hive JDBC (version 3.1.0.3.1.5.0-152)    
Beeline version 3.1.0.3.1.5.0-152 by Apache Hive
```

Note_1: I have already tried `--color=true` option while running beeline and it doesn't show beeline/Hive2 command prompt in different color.

[image]

Comment: If you only care about history and syntax highlighting, and not the actual terminal, how about using an external  SQL IDE environment or JDBC/ODBC tool instead that offers those features? Where is it documented that `--color` does something?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @OneCricketeer I'll check if I can use any SQL IDE. About the color property, I found it here https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/hiveserver2+clients. I'll try to attach an image in my question.